# Weird Routing Issue - No Method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a no method error when loading form for a nested resource. I have a fix for it but it's not right I'm sure.

My routes.rb contains:

```
resources :orders do
     resources :comments, :technicals, :milestones
end
```

At the top of my techncials.html.erb form I have this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for([@order, @technical]) do |f| %>
```

When loading the form, I get an error:

```
> NoMethodError in Technicals#new
> 
> undefined method `technicals_path' for
> #<#<Class:0x00000102118318>:0x000001020ec470>
```

If I then put this in my routes, it all works just fine:

```
resources :technicals, :only => [ :create ]
```

What on earth am I doing wrong, if anything??!

Edit: I think My models etc. are all set up correctly:

```
class Technical < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

-- edit --

```
company_order_comments GET    /companies/:company_id/orders/:order_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                           POST   /companies/:company_id/orders/:order_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
 new_company_order_comment GET    /companies/:company_id/orders/:order_id/comments/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
edit_company_order_comment GET    /companies/:company_id/orders/:order_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
     company_order_comment GET    /companies/:company_id/orders/:order_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                           PUT    /companies/:company_id/orders/:order_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                           DELETE /companies/:company_id/orders/:order_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
            company_orders GET    /companies/:company_id/orders(.:format)                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"orders"}
                           POST   /companies/:company_id/orders(.:format)                             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"orders"}
         new_company_order GET    /companies/:company_id/orders/new(.:format)                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"orders"}
        edit_company_order GET    /companies/:company_id/orders/:id/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"orders"}
             company_order GET    /companies/:company_id/orders/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders"}
                           PUT    /companies/:company_id/orders/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"orders"}
                           DELETE /companies/:company_id/orders/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"orders"}
                 companies GET    /companies(.:format)                                                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"companies"}
                           POST   /companies(.:format)                                                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"companies"}
               new_company GET    /companies/new(.:format)                                            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"companies"}
              edit_company GET    /companies/:id/edit(.:format)                                       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"companies"}
                   company GET    /companies/:id(.:format)                                            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"companies"}
                           PUT    /companies/:id(.:format)                                            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"companies"}
                           DELETE /companies/:id(.:format)                                            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"companies"}
            order_comments GET    /orders/:order_id/comments(.:format)                                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                           POST   /orders/:order_id/comments(.:format)                                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
         new_order_comment GET    /orders/:order_id/comments/new(.:format)                            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
        edit_order_comment GET    /orders/:order_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)                       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
             order_comment GET    /orders/:order_id/comments/:id(.:format)                            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                           PUT    /orders/:order_id/comments/:id(.:format)                            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                           DELETE /orders/:order_id/comments/:id(.:format)                            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
          order_technicals GET    /orders/:order_id/technicals(.:format)                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"technicals"}
                           POST   /orders/:order_id/technicals(.:format)                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"technicals"}
       new_order_technical GET    /orders/:order_id/technicals/new(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"technicals"}
      edit_order_technical GET    /orders/:order_id/technicals/:id/edit(.:format)                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"technicals"}
           order_technical GET    /orders/:order_id/technicals/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"technicals"}
                           PUT    /orders/:order_id/technicals/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"technicals"}
                           DELETE /orders/:order_id/technicals/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"technicals"}
          order_milestones GET    /orders/:order_id/milestones(.:format)                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"milestones"}
                           POST   /orders/:order_id/milestones(.:format)                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"milestones"}
       new_order_milestone GET    /orders/:order_id/milestones/new(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"milestones"}
      edit_order_milestone GET    /orders/:order_id/milestones/:id/edit(.:format)                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"milestones"}
           order_milestone GET    /orders/:order_id/milestones/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"milestones"}
                           PUT    /orders/:order_id/milestones/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"milestones"}
                           DELETE /orders/:order_id/milestones/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"milestones"}
                    orders GET    /orders(.:format)                                                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"orders"}
                           POST   /orders(.:format)                                                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"orders"}
                 new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)                                               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"orders"}
                edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)                                          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"orders"}
                     order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                                               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders"}
                           PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)                                               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"orders"}
                           DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)                                               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"orders"}
                                  /orders(.:format)                                                   {:controller=>"orders", :action=>"index"}
                      root        /(.:format)                                                         {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
```

Comment: Could you add in the output of rake routes, please?

Comment: sure, will edit question if that's ok. J

Comment: thanks :) at a quick glance it looks like the path name you need is new_order_technical_path. I'm jumping to this conclusion because I believe those _path methods are generated by taking the column at the far left and appending _path to them.

Comment: whoops., meant "order_technicals_path", sorry

Comment: Hi, the issue is that I'm not even using that anywhere in my views so I have no idea why it's moaning!!

Comment: oh, wow. I'll poke around again but my mind sputtered and smoked at this detail :) I'll pour coffee on my head and look again :)

Comment: semantic_form_for...that's Formtastic, no?

Comment: I believe nested forms require "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in the model (the containing model I'd assume).

Answer (score 0):

```
NoMethodError in Technicals#new
```

Does controllers/technicals_controller.rb have a "def new"?
If not, try adding one:

```
def new
 @technical = Technical.new
end
```